# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo

Here I am again with a problem I can't solve !
I'm getting this error and I don't quite get it.

[image]

After opening the DOM and reading the whole error and a lot of hours spend on Google, the only thing I got was that it looks like the error is triggered by this line of code:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
```

This is the Code where this line is :

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Image, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import firebase from 'firebase';
require('firebase/firestore');

function Profile(props) {
  const [userPosts, setUserPosts] = useState([]);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const { currentUser, posts } = props;
    console.log({ currentUser, posts });

    if (props.route.params.uid === firebase.auth().currentUser.uid) {
      setUser(currentUser);
      setUserPosts(posts);
    }
  });

  if (user === null) {
    return <View />;
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.containerInfo}>
        <Text> {user.name} </Text>
        <Text> {user.email} </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.containerGallery}>
        <FlatList
          numColumns={3}
          horizontal={false}
          data={userPosts}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={styles.containerImage}>
              <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: item.downloadURL }} />
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 40,
  },
  containerInfo: {
    margin: 20,
  },
  containerGallery: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  containerImage: {
    flex: 1 / 3,
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
  },
});

const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
  currentUser: store.userState.currentUser,
  posts: store.userState.posts,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Profile);
```

I'm making an Instagram Clone and if you need any other code I have, please tell me because I don't know what you all need to help me.

Comment: You import the whole firebase codebase with `import firebase from 'firebase'`, and then import the firestore service: `require('firebase/firestore')`, also mixing `require` and `import` operators. See the section named NPM Bundler (Browserify, Webpack, Rollup, etc.) in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase).

Comment: @Vadzim I don't get it, what has the error to do with that ?

Comment: try to replace `import firebase from 'firebase';
require('firebase/firestore');` with `import firebase from 'firebase/app'; import 'firebase/firestore';`

Comment: no still the same problem :/

Comment: In your redux you have store.userState, is that set up and initialised somewhere? All of the errors seem to be directly related to that, that would be the first place I'd look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error was triggered by this line of code

```
 setUser(currentUser);
```

The currentUser was not an object but a class and that triggered it. (That's what I understood)

So I replaced it with this:

```
setUser(firebase.auth().currentUser);
```

Now it works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

please use the Optional chaining operator

```
if (props.route?.params?.uid === firebase?.auth()?.currentUser?.uid) {
    setUser(currentUser);
    setUserPosts(posts);
}
```